# Read .csv file to pandas data frame and identify data sections from line breaks

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file where 2+ blank lines represent a new data section. But *a priori* I don't know how many lines are in each section. Is there a way to read directly to a pandas data frame and stop at the first 2+ blank lines?

The data are as follows (.csv files from Google Trends results, here truncated).

```
Web Search interest: zts
Worldwide; 2004 - present

Interest over time
Week,zts
2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,0
2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17,80


Top regions for zts
Region,zts
Slovakia,100
Slovenia,23


Top cities for zts
City,zts
Bratislava (Slovakia),100
Wroclaw (Poland),39



Top searches for zts
focus zts,100
ford zts,90



Rising searches for zts
2002 focus zts,Breakout
battery tester,Breakout
```

Now I use `csv.reader()` and loop over all the rows and retain rows that match a date regex in the first column and have two columns. But this seems hackish.

If I use something like `pandas.read_csv(input_file, header=4)` (then use a date regex later on to find the correct section), then it fails when the last section has three columns (here it doesn't, but it can).

Is there a way to stop my `pandas.read_csv()` after the first block without *a priori* knowing the number of rows? Ideally I would like to parse this .csv into five data frames (one for each data section), but at this point I'm happy grabbing the first section.

Comment: `read_csv` is for reading CSV files.  If your file isn't a CSV file, but multiple CSV files squished into one, then you can't directly use `read_csv`.  You should do like you suggested and preprocess the file to extract the separate CSV components.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's a good point. Just because someone squishes several .csv files into one doesn't mean that I should consider it one .csv. I was hoping to avoid temp .csv files, but that sounds like the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to *real* problem, which is that I should interpret my one .csv file as several .csv files and do this split outside of pandas.

```
import csv

section = 1
line = 1

output_root = 'C:/Users/richard/Downloads/out'
input_file = 'C:/Users/richard/Downloads/in.csv'

input = open(input_file, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(input)

for row in reader:
    if any(row) & (line == 1):
        output_file = output_root + '_' + str(section) + '.csv'
        output = open(output_file, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(row)
        line += 1
    elif any(row) & (line > 1):
        writer.writerow(row)
        line += 1
    elif (line > 1):
        output.close()
        section += 1
        line = 1

output.close()
input.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions. They work quite well for situations like this.

```
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO

csv1 = """right,top,bottom
4,5,6
6,7,8
"""

csv2 = """up,down,left
1,2,3
7,6,5
"""

csv3 = """a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
"""

join_n = randint(2, 6, size=2)
raw = [csv1, csv2, csv3]
csvs = []

for csv, n in zip(raw, join_n):
    csvs.append(csv + '\n' * n)

csvs.append(csv3)
csvs = ''.join(csvs)

splitsville = re.split('\n{2,}', csvs)

dfs = []

for sp in splitsville:
    dfs.append(read_csv(StringIO(sp)))


final_df = concat(dfs, axis=1)

print final_df
```

yields:

```
   right  top  bottom  up  down  left  a  b  c
0      4    5       6   1     2     3  1  2  3
1      6    7       8   7     6     5  4  5  6
```

**NOTE:** You don't necessarily have to `concat` the `list` of `DataFrame`s, but often that's a useful next step so that you don't have to keep operating on a `list` of `DataFrame`s.