# Pandas, how to stop reading csv after N rows?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some csv files I want to read, which for whatever reason is formatted like this

```
A B C
1 3 1
2 2 2
3 1 3


D
1
2
3
```

The problem here is that column D is below the other columns, and this makes Pandas very unhappy, once it finishes reading column A, and dives straight into D's column name string.

I can of course read it like

```
pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, nrows = rows_in_A_B_C)
```

Basically, `nrows = length_of_A_B_C`. Problem is, I don't know the number of rows before D, and I can't read the csv until I do.

How can I solve this? Can I stop reading rows based on a condition instead, such as when I hit the header for D?

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but you can move by hand the extra columns to a new file. Then you have two proper csv files which can be imported and then merged.

Comment: I'd shoot myself long before I did that to 1000+ files though ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34188535/6066986

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas - Read csv file containing multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184841/python-pandas-read-csv-file-containing-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer was already posted in the comments to the original post, but I still felt that they were needlessly hard to think up on the fly, for a rather simple task (or maybe I'm just bad, ha). In my case, I figured that the best method was as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype = "str", names = ["A","B","C"])
```

Now Pandas will fill out all the empty bottom rows with NaN, and this happens to mark all the rows that column D is contained in. All these rows can then be thrown away:

```
df = df[df["A"].str.contains("NaN") == False]
```

And because we need it as a numeric dataframe,

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

And now this can be used for skipping rows for parsing D only:

```
D_only = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = len(df["A"])
```

And concatenated with `pd.concat(df, D_only), axis=1)`

Disclaimer: I don't know how efficient this is, computationally.