# Parse multiple tables of different sizes from a single csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file that contains multiple tables. Each table has a title, and variable number of rows and columns (these numbers may vary between files). The titles, as well as names of rows and columns may also change between different files I will need to parse in the future, so I cannot hardcode them. some columns may contain empty cells as well.

Here is a screenshot of an example CSV file with this structure:
[image]

I need to find a solution that will parse all the tables from the CSV into Pandas DFs. Ideally the final output would be an Excel file, where each table is saved as a sheet, and the name of each sheet will be the corresponding table title.

I tried the suggested solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184841/python-pandas-read-csv-file-containing-multiple-tables) but it kept failing in identifying the start/end of the tables. When I used a simpler version of the input csv file, the suggested code only returned one table.

I would appreciate any assistance!!

Comment: If tables are separated by an empty row, you can just check whether the row is empty for every row you process. Once a row is empty, you can then start processing the next table

Comment: Thank you @AlexandruCristiean! Could you please share a basic code example to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

dfs = []
start = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if all(row.isna()):  # Empty row
        # Remove empty columns
        temp_df = df.loc[start:i, :].dropna(how="all", axis=1)
        if start:  # Grab header, except for first df
            new_header = temp_df.iloc[0]
            temp_df = temp_df[1:]
            temp_df.columns = new_header
        temp_df = temp_df.dropna(how="all", axis=0)
        dfs.append(temp_df)
        start = i + 1
```

Then, you can reach each df by calling `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`, ...

Comment: Thanks @Laurent! a couple of issues are that : 1. The code won't read the last table in the csv file. and 2. it adds an extra blank row to each table.

Comment: Thanks again! removing the extra blank row worked perfectly! However, I couldn't get the last table to parse. I checked and there's no extra blank row. Interestingly, if I add a blank row and a dummy data row after the last table, the script will read that table and ignore the dummy data row.

Comment: I was also wondering, why did you add the part that discards the first table? is that necessary? How should the code be modified to also parse the first table?

Comment: When I try it in its current form, the code doesn't t save the first df to the dfs list.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, `dfs.append(temp_df)` was not properly indented, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Laurent!! for some strange reason it keeps skipping the last table in the CSV file... I'll keep digging.

Comment: @AdiLavy, did you find any solutions why it keeps skiping the last table?

Comment: I did not... sorry