# Split CSV file which contains multiple tables into different pandas dataFrames (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, txt

I have multiple CSV files which are formatted with multiple tables inside separated by line breaks.

Example:

```
Technology  C_inv [MCHF/y]  C_maint [MCHF/y]
NUCLEAR 70.308020   33.374568
HYDRO_DAM_EXISTING  0.000000    195.051200
HYDRO_DAM   67.717942   1.271600
HYDRO_RIVER_EXISTING    0.000000    204.820000
IND_BOILER_OIL  2.053610    0.532362
IND_BOILER_COAL 4.179935    1.081855
IND_BOILER_WASTE    11.010126   2.849652
DEC_HP_ELEC 554.174644  320.791276
DEC_THERMAL_HP_GAS  77.077291   33.717477
DEC_BOILER_GAS  105.586089  41.161335
DEC_BOILER_OIL  33.514266   25.948450
H2_FROM_GAS 145.185290  59.178082
PYROLYSIS   132.200818  112.392123

Storage technology  C_inv [MCHF/y]  C_maint [MCHF/y]
HYDRO_STORAGE   0.000000    0.000000

Resource    C_op [MCHF/y]
ELECTRICITY 1174.452848
GASOLINE    702.000000
DIESEL  96.390000
OIL 267.787558
NG  1648.527242
WOOD    592.110000
COAL    84.504083
URANIUM 18.277626
WASTE   0.000000
```

All my CSV files have different subtable names but few enough that I could enter them manually to detect them if required.

Another issue is that many titles include spaces (eg "Storage Technology") which is read by pandas as 2 columns.

I initially tried to do it directly with pandas and splitting manually but the argument `on_bad_lines='skip'` which allows avoiding errors also skips useful lines:

```
Cost_bd = pd.read_csv(f"{Directory}/cost_breakdown.csv",on_bad_lines='skip',delim_whitespace=True).dropna(axis=1,how='all')
colnames=['Technnolgy', 'C_inv[MCHF/y]', 'C_maint[MCHF/y]'] 
Cost_bd.columns = colnames
```

I believe it might be better to scan the `.txt` file and split it but I'm unsure how to do this in the best way.

I have also tried to use the solution provided in this [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184841/python-pandas-read-csv-file-containing-multiple-tables)

```
import csv
from os.path import dirname # gets parent folder in a path
from os.path import join # concatenate paths
table_names = ["Technology", "Storage technology", "Resource"]

df = pd.read_csv(f"{Directory}/cost_breakdown.csv", header=None, names=range(3))
groups = df[0].isin(table_names).cumsum()
tables = {g.iloc[0,0]: g.iloc[1:] for k,g in df.groupby(groups)}
```

but it doesn't work:

```
tables.keys()=
dict_keys(['Technology\tC_inv [MCHF/y]\tC_maint [MCHF/y]'])
```

EDIT : Final solution based on @Rabinzel:

```
import re
def make_df(group,dict_of_dfs):
    header, data = re.split(r'\t',group[0]), list(map(str.split, group[1:]))
    if len(header) != len(data[0]): # If missing columns list, take former
        header  = header + dict_of_dfs[list(dict_of_dfs.keys())[0]].columns.tolist()[1:]
    dict_of_dfs[header[0]] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    return dict_of_dfs

def Read_csv_as_df(path, file_name):
    
    with open(path+file_name) as f:
            dict_of_dfs = {}
            group = []
            for line in f:
                if line!='\n':
                    group.append(line.strip())
                else:
                    print(dict_of_dfs)
                    dict_of_dfs = make_df(group,dict_of_dfs)
                    group = []
            dict_of_dfs = make_df(group,dict_of_dfs)
    return dict_of_dfs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the following way.
Iterate through each row, append each chunk seperated by a newline to a list and build dataframes from the lists. The problem with the column names with spaces, use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and split only if there are two or more spaces.
Save the different df's in a dictionary where the key is the first element of the header of each df.

```
import re
def make_df(group):
    header, data = re.split(r'\s\s+',group[0]), list(map(str.split, group[1:]))
    dict_of_dfs[header[0]] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)

with open('your_csv_file.csv') as f:
    dict_of_dfs = {}
    group = []
    for line in f:
        if line!='\n':
            group.append(line.strip())
        else:
            make_df(group)
            group = []
    make_df(group)

for key, value in dict_of_dfs.items():
    print(f"{key=}\ndf:\n{value}\n---------------------")
```

Output:

```
key='Technology'
df:
              Technology C_inv [MCHF/y] C_maint [MCHF/y]
0                NUCLEAR      70.308020        33.374568
1     HYDRO_DAM_EXISTING       0.000000       195.051200
2              HYDRO_DAM      67.717942         1.271600
3   HYDRO_RIVER_EXISTING       0.000000       204.820000
4         IND_BOILER_OIL       2.053610         0.532362
5        IND_BOILER_COAL       4.179935         1.081855
6       IND_BOILER_WASTE      11.010126         2.849652
7            DEC_HP_ELEC     554.174644       320.791276
8     DEC_THERMAL_HP_GAS      77.077291        33.717477
9         DEC_BOILER_GAS     105.586089        41.161335
10        DEC_BOILER_OIL      33.514266        25.948450
11           H2_FROM_GAS     145.185290        59.178082
12             PYROLYSIS     132.200818       112.392123
---------------------
key='Storage technology'
df:
  Storage technology C_inv [MCHF/y] C_maint [MCHF/y]
0      HYDRO_STORAGE       0.000000         0.000000
---------------------
key='Resource'
df:
      Resource C_op [MCHF/y]
0  ELECTRICITY   1174.452848
1     GASOLINE    702.000000
2       DIESEL     96.390000
3          OIL    267.787558
4           NG   1648.527242
5         WOOD    592.110000
6         COAL     84.504083
7      URANIUM     18.277626
8        WASTE      0.000000
---------------------
```

Comment: In function `make_df` you can have `key = header[0]` to make the key names the table names.

Comment: thanks, that makes propably more sense. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I ended up implementing a solution but yours is much cleaner. I tried to run yours but it returns me that error:
ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Do you know where the issue would be?

Comment: I guess in your data you have columns (I think headers) where between elements isn't 2 or more spaces, then they won't get splitted. Pandas expects a list of 3 names (3 columns) but only got one big string with 3 names (1 column)

Comment: Though it is the same file that I posted here. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Could you run my code again and add `print(line)` directly after `for line in f`. Then we see at which line in the file the code throws the error.

Comment: ... PYROLYSIS 132.200818 112.392123
 Right after:
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns.
So the error pops up at the second table

Comment: Ok. I took another look on how you provided the example data. I saved it as text file, and there I have 2 spaces between "Storage technology" and "C_inv [MCHF/y]" but maybe in your data the names are seperated by `\t`. Try to run my code with a little change from `re.split(r'\s\s+',group[0])` to `re.split(r'\t',group[0])`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: It works! I also had to change `make_df(group)` to make it work as a function `dict_of_dfs = make_df(group,dict_of_dfs)`.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @OliviaJ nice, happy to hear! You can thank me by accepting the answer :)

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. I put also my latest version with a slight twist when we don't have a repetition of columns names as Edit to my post.