# Split text file after specific line in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code to read Fresco files and plot the results. Fresco produces one big file that looks something like this

```
theta  sigma
1        0.1
2        0.1
3        0.2
...
END
some text...
theta   sigma
1        0.3
2        0.2
...
END
more data...
```

I want to produce a new file after every 'END' to analyze the data separately. I tried some of the solutions proposed to other answers like

```
with open('fort.16', 'r') as infile, open('output_fort.16', 'w') as outfile:
copy= False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == '# legend':
        copy = True
        continue
    elif line.strip()=='End':
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

but this is not what i need. 
Im fairly new to python so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `infile.read().split("END")`?

Comment: @Filip if the file is large this won't work

Comment: How can we distinguish between the `some text...` rows, and the `theta   sigma` header row? Do we know the header will always be the same `theta   sigma` throughout the sections, or can it change (arbitrarily)? Is it guaranteed that the `some text...` rows don't contain numbers? (Btw, it would be useful to prefix the some text...` rows with `#` to make them comments, which would get ignored.)

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: @smci Well we know that every "file" ends with END so we can split it there

Comment: Please answer the other stuff: Do we know the header will always be the same theta sigma throughout the sections, or can it change (arbitrarily)? Is it guaranteed that the `some text...` row(s) don't contain numbers? Or else are they guaranteed to be exactly one line? How else do we distinguish them from the next header?

Comment: *but this is not what i need.* - why? what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Filip the problem could be that the file doesn't fit in memory. So how big can the file be?

Comment: If you're ok with using `pandas` library, this is easy to implement: [Read .csv file to pandas data frame and identify data sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492283/read-csv-file-to-pandas-data-frame-and-identify-data-sections-from-line-breaks). You can implement it so it doesn't need to read in all the lines up front and store it in one huge buffer.

Comment: I don't think the file can be that big? I assume 8gigs of ram are available, but I don't know how big the files can be

Comment: you could use recursion. I am busy right now but if you give me a bit i can solve it for you.

Comment: "this is not what i need" What does your code do differently than what you want?

Comment: @Code-Apprenticei gave him the answer but he hasnt accepted it. He probably just left

Comment: Also you can find the line numbers with something like `grep --line-number -E "^(theta.*sigma|END)$" fort.16` and optimize your script to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this with a nested generator:

```
import re

SECTION_START = re.compile(r'^\s*theta\s+sigma\s*$')
SECTION_END = re.compile(r'^\s*END\s*$')

def fresco_iter(stream):
    def inner(stream):
        # Yields each line until an end marker is found (or EOF)
        for line in stream:
            if line and not SECTION_END.match(line):
                yield line
                continue
            break

    # Find a start marker, then break off into a nested iterator
    for line in stream:
        if line:
            if SECTION_START.match(line):
                yield inner(stream)
            continue
        break
```

The `fresco_iter` method returns a generator that can be for-looped over. It returns 1 generator per section of `theta sigma` pairs.

```
>>> with open('fort.16', 'r') as fh:
...     print(list(fresco_iter(fh)))
[<generator object fresco_iter.<locals>.inner at 0x7fbc6da15678>,
 <generator object fresco_iter.<locals>.inner at 0x7fbc6da15570>]
```

So to make use of this, you create your own nested loop to process the nested generators.

```
filename = 'fort.16'

with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    for nested_iter in fresco_iter(fh):
        print('--- start')
        for line in nested_iter:
            print(line.rstrip())
        print('--- end')
```

would output...

```
--- start
1        0.1
2        0.1
3        0.2
--- end
--- start
1        0.3
2        0.2
--- end
```

This strategy only ever holds 1 line of your input file in memory at a time, so would work for any size file, on even the smallest device... because generators are awesome.

So to take it all the way... separating the output into individual files:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fh_in:
    for (i, nested_iter) in enumerate(fresco_iter(fh_in)):
        with open('{}.part-{:04d}'.format(filename, i), 'w') as fh_out:
            for line in nested_iter:
                fh_out.write(line)
```

Will output *just* the numbers to separate files named `fort.16.part-0000` and `fort.16.part-0001`.

I hope this helps, happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

```
fp = open("random.txt")

data = []
temp = []

for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if line.strip() == "END":
        new_file = open("file"+str(i)+".txt", "a+")
        for i in temp:
            new_file.write(i+"\n")
        temp = []
        new_file.close()
        continue
    temp.append(line.strip())

fp.close()
print(data)
```

Here you go this one, creates a new file everytime. The file name is file and the index of where ever the "END" line was found. :)